# Methods to replace storyboard reference in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, storyboard-reference

At the beginning of the development of my app, I used storyboard reference since it's very convenient in team development. However it only supports those systems that are new than iOS 9. Now I've completed the development, but how can I use another approach to replace storyboard reference so I can support older systems?(I only use this single technique that requires a iOS 9.0+ system)

Comment: Storyboard references are available in iOS 8 read at bottom of page. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AddSBReference.html

Comment: storyboard reference can be used in iOS 8 also, and its perfectly fine for drop support for iOS 7 nowadays, maybe its like lesser than 5%

Comment: But if I set the deployment target of my app to iOS 8.0, then it will throw a build error:`Storyboard References cannot be the destinations of relationship segues prior to iOS 9.0`

Comment: I use the storyboard reference in `UITabBarController`